# SAS Table merge

Tags: sas

I need to create a table "abc.xlsx" and I  have read a lot of material for doing this, but was unable to find useful information.

I have a file names which contain product name and its description's. like attributes of product.

What I need to do is?

Create a proc output and store in an excel.

```
PROC Tabulate data=ABC   FORMAT=COMMA10. ORDER=formatted Missing out= test
(drop = _TABLE_ _TYPE_ _PAGE_ );

CLASS  DEG_COLLEGE_DEAN GENDER ADM_TYPE COHORT_TERM COHORT_YEAR Year_Track_Deg_4;

 TABLE  GENDER*DEG*(Year='')*N='' ALL, Year;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYvkG.png)

```
run;
```

Similarly, we have more than 20 proc tabulate statement and I need to merge it on the basis of one indicator variable and indicator id.

I am getting an output in tabular format and I am creating an indicator variable to select  which indicator to select to get an output.

Comment: I don't see a clear and concise question here, sorry.  Narrow this down, maybe one problem at a time, and give example data and example desired result.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you wish to "Create a [proc] output and store in an excel". Apologies if this does not answer your question.

There are number of ways to export data from SAS, but an easy way to output in excel format is to use proc export. (Sas manual ref:http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/69850/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n045uxf7ll2p5on1ly4at3vpd47e.htm)

I suggest you do formatting in sas and export the whole file like this:

```
PROC EXPORT DATA= WORK.DataSet_to_export
        OUTFILE= "C:\output_folder\Output_FileName" 
        DBMS=XLS LABEL REPLACE;
        NEWFILE=YES; 
RUN;
```

However the DBMS (delimiter definition) may not be available in your version of sas. Using comma separated format insted:

```
proc export data=DataSet_to_export
    outfile="C:\output_folder\Output_FileName.csv"  
    dbms=DLM REPLACE;  
    delimiter = ";";  
run;
```

You can replace dlimiter as you wish. However, excel has little trouble importing ';' separated data.